# Some mathematical magic

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, magic

The magician will perform some mathematical magic.
He asks his guest to secretly pick any two digit number and then perform a number of operations on it.

1. If the number is even, divide by 2, if it is odd subtract 3 and then divide by 2.
2. Multiply by 3.
3. Add 5.
4. If the number has 3 digits, subtract 102.
5. Multiply by 6.
6. Subtract 21.
7. Compute the sum of the digits and continue with this sum. For example if you have 41, continue computing with 5=4+1. *
8. If the number has only a single digit, multiply by 2.
9. Subtract 5.

At this point, the magician reveals the number the guest arrived at after step 9.

How does this trick work?

**Edit:** * As noted in the comments, it can happen that you have a negative number at this point. In this case just ignore the minus sign in front. So for example the sum of digits of -16 would be 7.

Comment: What do you do in step 7 if the number is negative? Treat the sum as negative? (This  occurs if you begin with 64, 66, 67, or 69.)

Comment: @NickMatteo Nice catch, when setting the problem up, I didn't notice this could be negative. If you just ignore the negative sign, everything works out as expected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number chosen is somewhere between $10$ and $99$.

1. > After the first step, we have a number $n$ which is between $4$ and $48$.
2. > After the next two steps, we have $3n+5$ which is between $17$ and $147$.
3. > After the fourth step, we have either $3n+5$ or $3n-97$ which is less than $100$. Call this new number $m$; it is congruent to $2$ modulo $3$.
4. > After the next two steps, we have $6m-21=3(2m-7)$, which is an odd number and a multiple of $9$ since $m\equiv2\;(mod\;3)$.
5. > The digit sum of a multiple of $9$ is always a multiple of $9$, so after the next step we have either $9$ or $18$ (it can't be as high as $27$ since anything less than $999$ won't have such a big digit sum).
6. > After the 8th step, we have $18$ for sure.

So the final answer is

> $13$. Unlucky!

Comment: @NickMatteo Thanks, fixed that. Yeah, it doesn't matter to the conclusion; in the early stages I was just including all the bounds I could see, not knowing exactly where this was going.

Comment: Your step 4 might be a bit clearer if you put it in terms of n. I spent a while looking at the equation and wondering how you concluded it was a multiple of 9 before I realised that it was because m was constrained. Having it in terms of n will make it much clearer that it is a multiple of 9 since you can just take that factor out.

Comment: @Chris I can't put it directly in terms of $n$ since there are two different options for $m$ in terms of $n$, but I added an extra clause to clarify.

Comment: I was just thinking adding something like "which is 18n+9 or 18n-603 which can be factored as 9(2n+1) or 9(2n-67)".This is much what you did in step 3 where you showed the two possible totals depending on whether you needed to subtract 102 or not.